# auth.onAuthStateChanged on vue3 and firebase 9.0.0 beta.3 not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

** Update **
I got it to work with the following
**main.js **

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from './firebase'

let app
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
  }

  if (user) {
    //store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
  }
})
```

** firebase.js **

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // config settings
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// utils
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
// collection references
const usersCollection = collection(db, "users")
const postsCollection = collection(db, "posts")
const commentsCollection = collection(db, "comments")
const likesCollection = collection(db, "likes")
export {
  db,
  auth,
  usersCollection,
  postsCollection,
  commentsCollection,
  likesCollection
};
```

** When created vue3 and npm run serves it works.**

But when add auth.onAuthStateChanged to main.js and npm run serve than it show blank page.
I already try auth.auth().onAuthStateChanged not worked

** main.js **

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { auth } from './firebase'

let app
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
  }

  if (user) {
    //store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
  }
})
```

** firebase.js **

```
/* eslint-disable */
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';


const firebaseConfig = {
  //... config
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// utils
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const authProvider = firebase.auth;

// collection references
const usersCollection = db.collection('users');
const postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
const commentsCollection = db.collection('comments');
const likesCollection = db.collection('likes');

// export utils/refs
export {
  db,
  auth,
  authProvider,
  firebase,
  usersCollection,
  postsCollection,
  commentsCollection,
  likesCollection
};
```

** I tried another way but not worked **

**  main.js **

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { auth, authState } from './firebase';

let app
authState(auth, (user) => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
  }

  if (user) {
    //store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
  }
})
```

** firebase.js**

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  \\ config
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// utils
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
const authState = onAuthStateChanged();
const googleAuthProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();

// collection references
const usersCollection = db.collection('users');
const postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
const commentsCollection = db.collection('comments');
const likesCollection = db.collection('likes');

// export utils/refs
export {
  db,
  auth,
  authState,
  googleAuthProvider,
  firebaseApp,
  usersCollection,
  postsCollection,
  commentsCollection,
  likesCollection
};
```

** Another question **
Is it good practice to code like above

Thanks

Comment: If you were able to find a solution to your problem, _post it as an answer_. In addition, asking about good practices turns the question into an opinion-based one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer this even tho OP already solved it.

You have to pass the firebaseApp instance to the getAuth function in Firebase 9.0. This is because you could be using different firebase instances in the same app.

Example code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  ...
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const authInstance = getAuth(firebaseApp);

onAuthStateChanged(authInstance, user => console.log(user));
```